# Objective C, Return an Array

Tags: objective-c

```
 -(NSArray*)getNeighbors{
      NSArray *values = [neighbors allValues];//neighbors is NSMutableDictionary
      return values;
 }
```

I have a very simple code like this but I am not sure that I need to add "retain"...

Comment: Don't call it getNeighbors.  Just 'neighbors' is the standard pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're going to do with returned value. -[NSArray allValues] returns new array, which is autoreleased, so if you're planning to use that array for a long time (outside the function scope) then you should retain it (but not in  -(NSArray*)getNeighbors). Retain array (if needed outside):

```
-(void) foo {
    ivar_array = [[someObject getNeighbors] retain];
}
```

OR the case when you don't need to retain:

```
-(void) foo {
   NSArray* array= [someObject getNeighbors];
   //do something with that array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't. The method that calls `getNeighbors` should take care of retaining the returned array.

Answer (score 0):

You can send `retain` and `release` to every object inherited from `NSObject`, depending on your needs. But in your case `values` is an object which you don't own, and you should take special care of how you handle it. For more information, consult [Object Ownership and Disposal](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't. This page([1](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html)) has detailed explanation.